# SQLAlchemy selecting a column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I select all of the last element of Facture, I know I can use a for loop but I thought there would be a faster way to select with SQLAlchemy.
I want [99,15,90,20,16,14,100]

```
>>> Facture.numero_facture
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x0000025640056770>

>>> Facture.query.all()
[Facture('Photographe', '2021-11-01', 99), Facture('Auchan', '2021-11-02', 15), Facture('Auchan', '2021-11-01', 90), Facture('test', '2021-11-01', 20), Facture('a', '2021-11-01', 16), Facture('Auchan', '2021-11-01', 14), Facture('g', '2021-11-10', 100)]

class Facture(db.Model):
        # import datetime
        # today = datetime.datetime.today()
        # date = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        # Créer une database où on va ajouter du code chaque fois
        id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key=True)
        numero_facture = db.Column(db.Integer(), unique=True)
        date = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
        nom_societe = db.Column(db.String(length=200), nullable=False)
        adresse = db.Column(db.String(length=200), nullable=False)
        code_postal = db.Column(db.Integer(),nullable=True)
        ville = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=True)
        items = db.relationship("Item", backref="facture", lazy=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            # return f"Facture_details('{self.numero_facture}', '{self.date}, '{self.nom_societe}, '{self.adresse}, '{self.code_postal}, '{self.ville})"
            # return f"Facture_details('{self.nom_societe}', '{self.date})"
            return f"Facture('{self.nom_societe}', '{self.date}', {self.numero_facture})"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Facture.query[0:5]
>>> Facture.query[-5:]
```

But how do you know which of them are the last? You might want to add some kind of order_by, probably something like:

```
>>> Facture.query.order_by(Facture.date.desc)[0:5]
```

OK, as I understand now you want only one column. You have a session object somewhere - I cannot see there it is in your code. Is it flask_sqlalchemy? Then you can do:

```
session.query(Facture.numero_facture)[0:5]
```

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for but this is good, I had no idea I could select them this way!

Comment: What were you looking for then?

Comment: Sorry can't seem I can write some code here. But if there was any way I could use SQLAlchemy to generate the same output from this code : `all = Facture.query.all()
        facture_list = []
        for facture_temp in all:
            facture_list.append(facture_temp.numero_facture)` >>> facture_list
[99, 15, 90, 20, 16, 14, 100]

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! This worked >>> db.session.query(Facture.numero_facture).all()                   
[(14,), (15,), (16,), (20,), (90,), (99,), (100,), (101,), (102,), (103,), (104,), (105,), (106,)]